# How to reset HTML form in yew

Tags: rust, yew

I am trying to get a grip on Yew with a simple form input page.

```rust
//... imports
// I have redacted some code. RecipeItemProps is a simple three string struct
#[derive(Properties, PartialEq)]
pub struct RecipeFormProps {
    pub ingredients: Vec<RecipeItemProps>,
}

#[function_component]
fn RecipeForm(props: &RecipeFormProps) -> Html {
    let app_state = use_state(|| Vec::from(props.ingredients.clone()));

    let add_ingridient_callback = {
        let app_state = app_state.clone();
        Callback::from(move |event: SubmitEvent| {
            let target: EventTarget = event.target().unwrap();
            let form = target.dyn_into::<HtmlFormElement>().ok();

            if let Some(form) = form {
                let form_data = FormData::new_with_form(&form).unwrap();
                let name: JsValue = form_data.get("ingridient");
                let amount: JsValue = form_data.get("amount");
                let quantity: JsValue = form_data.get("quantity");

                let mut myvec = app_state.to_vec();
                myvec.push(RecipeItemProps {
                    name: name.as_string().unwrap(),
                    amount: amount.as_string().unwrap(),
                    quantity: quantity.as_string().unwrap(),
                });
                app_state.set(myvec);
            }
            event.prevent_default();
        })
    };
   // I generate html here
```

However, I would like to reset form input fields in `add_ingridient_callback` on submit. I cannot figure out how to actually do this. In react `event.target.reset()` would achieve this. How could I manage this in yew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in `HtmlFormElement` called `reset` which resets the form inputs.

```rust
if let Some(form) = form {
    let form_data = FormData::new_with_form(&form).unwrap();
    let name: JsValue = form_data.get("ingridient");
    let amount: JsValue = form_data.get("amount");
    let quantity: JsValue = form_data.get("quantity");

    web_sys::console::log_1(&name);
    web_sys::console::log_1(&amount);
    web_sys::console::log_1(&quantity);

    let mut myvec = app_state.to_vec();
    myvec.push(RecipeItemProps {
        name: name.as_string().unwrap(),
        amount: amount.as_string().unwrap(),
        quantity: quantity.as_string().unwrap(),
    });                
    // Inserted reset
    form.reset();
```

Why is missed this before, I cannot say. It is literally the same code as in the example.